# Django Update field of three models with same name via ModelForm Field

Tags: python, django, forms, models

I've created a form that has a notes field and when the end user fills in the notes field and hits submit i need it to not only save the text in ModelOne Notes but also update the notes field in ModelTwo & ModelThree with the same text.

Current Code:

View.py

```
class CommandRadioView(FormView):
template_name = 'Gameflow/command_call_notes.html'
form_class = CommandCallForm

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.mission = get_object_or_404(Mission, pk=kwargs.get('mission_id', None))
    kwargs['user_id'] = self.mission.proposal.user.id
    self.radio = get_object_or_404(CommandPhone, pk=kwargs.get('radio_id', None))
    phone_type = CommandPhoneCallType(
        description=' General Comm',
        phonecall=self.radio
    )
    phone_type.save()
    self.mission.complete_mission(
        request.user,
        self.radio.created_at
    )
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if "save" in request.POST:
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        url = self.get_success_url()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Form.py:

```
class CommandCallForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Mission
    fields = ['notes']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_id = 'user_form'
    self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-3'
    self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'

    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Field(
            'notes',
        ),
        FormActions(
            Submit('save', 'Submit'),
            Button('cancel', 'Cancel', css_class='cancel')
        )
    )
```

Anything missing what you need to view just let me know cheers.

Comment: Where's your form? There's literally nothing on the post request method?

Comment: @FazilZaid   Added form code, Yes i know this is only the seond time i've found myself having to use post and i'm not sure on the query needed to do multiple models

Comment: Could you please explain what is it that you are trying to achieve? I couldn't quite understand..

Comment: @FazilZaid No problem so i have a notes field on this form which is linked to the Mission model but i also need to update two other Models that have a notes field with the same text that is entered in this form when submit is clicked

Comment: could you show the models as well for a better understanding?

Comment: @FazilZaid Not particularly as it's a lot of code, all i'm after is just some code logic or a nudge in what direction i go in for this as i just can't find anything online relating to this question

Comment: Is this mission_id, radio_id are in the notes or its just in the request.POST?

Answer (score 0):

From what you asked, and what I understood, I have edited your views,

Like this,

```
class CommandRadioView(FormView):
    template_name = 'Gameflow/command_call_notes.html'
    form_class = CommandCallForm            

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            self.mission = get_object_or_404(Mission, pk=kwargs.get('mission_id', None))
            kwargs['user_id'] = self.mission.proposal.user.id
            self.radio = get_object_or_404(CommandPhone, pk=kwargs.get('radio_id', None))
            phone_type = CommandPhoneCallType(description=' General Comm', phonecall=self.radio)
            phone_type.save()
            self.mission.complete_mission(request.user, self.radio.created_at)
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```